# An error for converting from type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<ClassX>' to 'ClassX'

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio-2008, casting, iqueryable

I have a Linq query that returns an object of the type `IQueryable<ClassX>`. I want to put this object into object of class type `ClassX` and getting an error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type `'System.Linq.IQueryable<ClassX>'` to
>   `'ClassX'`. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

This is what I'm trying to do:
`GetResult()` returns the `IQueryable<ClassX>` object.

```
ClassX x = GetResult();
```

I've tried casting such as `ClassX x = (ClassX)(GetResult());` - but it didn't work.

Comment: An `IQueryable<T>` represents a query that may return zero, one, or many instances of type `T`. As such, trying to put it in a variable of type `T` doesn't make sense - there are various answers now being posted for how to deal with this.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I'm new in Linq.. (+1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you're probably aware, your LINQ query returns `IQueryable<ClassX>`. That represents a query with a result set. It doesn't represent the object in the result itself, so you can't just cast it like that.

If your method will return exactly one `ClassX` object, you can use `.Single()` to grab that object from the result set:

```
ClassX x = GetResult().Single();
```

Or `.SingleOrDefault()` if the result set may be empty:

```
ClassX x = GetResult().SingleOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 2):

IQueryable is "collection" of objects, so to assign to "type item of an element in the collection" you need to pick a single item.

Depending on what you need First, [Skip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx), [FirstOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx) would let you to pick an item from the IQueryable/IEnumerable:

```
ClassX x = GetResult().FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var temp = GetResult().AsEnumerable().SingleOrDefault();
```